# How can I decipher a substitution cipher?

Tags: linux

I have a ciphered text file where `A=I` `a=i` `!=h` etc., I know the right substitutions. How can I generate a readable form of the text?

I have read that it's [Substitution Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher)

Comment: This is probably more suitable for StackOverflow... but even there, you'd need to at least give it a go - provide some code, tell us what went wrong, etc...

Comment: This is a good homework assignment for a beginner programming student.  One of the pitfalls you may find while you are solving it is that you need to avoid decrypting already-decrypted portions.  If all you need is a solution to one cipher, I've put an answer below for some websites that will do it for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
tr 'Aa!' 'Iih'
```

This performs the following transformations: `A`→`I`, `a`→`i`, `!`→`h`. If you want the other way around as well (`A`→`I`, `I`→`A`, …), the command is

```
tr 'Aa!Iih' 'IihAa!'
```

The N-th character of the first set is converted to the N-th character of the second set. Read `man 1 tr` for more information.

Please note that GNU `tr`, which you have on Linux, doesn't really have a concept of multibyte characters, but instead works one byte at a time; so if your substitutions involve non-ASCII multibyte UTF-8 characters, the command won't work as expected.

Comment: @kamil-maciorowski. Thanks, I think this will pretty much solve my problems because it lets me all the cipher rule at once. My challenge was how to set that rule and your answer provides that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use CyberChef or another encryption tool:

[Deciphering](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Substitute('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','XYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW')&input=QUJDREVGR0hJSktMTU5PUFFSU1RVVldYWVo)
is fairly simple. Just select the Substitute operation and put it into the recipe, then place your key in line with your values such that keys and values are lined up in a column.

CyberChef was created by the GCHQ of Britain.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/788749)

Comment: @Toto I highly doubt the GCHQ will ever remove CyberChef. It's also downloadable. It's just an html page.

Comment: @varfirstName , it's a very common thing for URLs to be changed in the future.  "Link rot" isn't just from takedowns.  It's better to give answers that will still be true in general after years.

Answer (score 0):

A Google search for "solve substitution cipher" yields several websites which can solve it for you.  https://quipqiup.com  https://www.guballa.de/substitution-solver